# In depletion MOSFETs, what is the drain current value when \$V_{GS}\$ is zero?

Tags: mosfet, depletion-mode

When \$V_{GS}\$ is very negative \$I_D=0\$, whereas it conducts a little current when \$V_{GS}\$ is a little negative.

What is the value of \$I_D\$ when \$V_{GS}=0\$?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of \$I_{DS}\$ when \$V_{GS}=0\$ is called \$I_{DSS}\$ on datasheets.

Consider for example the following excerpt from [Supertex DN3545 datasheet](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en570590).

[image]